# API: Argument dwExtraInfo gets overwritten

Tags: windows, api, winapi

I am synthesizing a mouse event using SendInput as shown below.
It all worked fine. When I used a mouse hook to detect the synthesized value (or just use ProcMon), I got just what I send. To be specific, dwExtraInfo was still 1024.

Now when I use Windows 7, dwExtraInfo will automatically be replaced by Windows with a number: -11054848. I don't know where that comes from, and I did not find any information about this on MSDN.

At first I thought that Windows just "AND"ed a value to my value, but I guess that is not the case.

Does anybody know what is going on here?

```
Dim inputevents(0) As INPUT_Type   ' holds information about each event

Dim mouseevent As MOUSEINPUT  ' temporarily hold mouse input info

With mouseevent
    .dX = 0  ' no horizontal movement
    .dy = 0  ' no vertical movement
    .mouseData = 0
    .dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN
    .dwTime = 0  ' use the default
    .dwExtraInfo = 1024 'this is my custom value
End With

' Copy the structure into the input array's buffer.
inputevents(0).dwType = INPUT_MOUSE  ' mouse input
CopyMemory inputevents(0).xi(0), mouseevent, Len(mouseevent)

' Now that all the information for the four input events has been placed
' into the array, finally send it into the input stream.
Dim lRet&
lRet = SendInput(1, inputevents(0), Len(inputevents(0)))
```

And this is how I read the Windows Message.
I guess I am quite experienced, and it always worked fine:

```
        Dim nMouseDat As WinSubHook2.tMSLLHOOKSTRUCT   'Low-level mouse data
        'lParam points to the low-level mouse data, copy it to dat
        nMouseDat = hkMs.xMSLLHOOKSTRUCT(lParam)
        'Here nMouseDat.dwExtraInfo should be 1024, but instead it is -11054848
```

Comment: This is only part of the code. We can't see the type declarations. Not can we see the code that calls GetMessageExtraInfo

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You're right. I have edited my posting and added the hook code. On pre-Windows-7 versions that always worked the way I expected.

Comment: Standard 64-bit lossage.  Way too much VB6 code so MOUSEINPUT.dwExtraInfo is probably not declared as an IntPtr.  Len() is fundamentally wrong, CopyMemory is pointless.

Comment: @HansPassant dwExtraInfo is a VB6 Long, both when I use SendInput as well as in the hook.

Comment: We can't see the type declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 7 generates extra message info for messages in the range `WM_MOUSEFIRST` to `WM_MOUSELAST` to allow a client to query the origin of a mouse input message. The reason for this is that Windows generates mouse input in response to touch input, to provide minimal support for applications that do not implement dedicated touch support.

This is documented at [System Events and Mouse Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703320.aspx). The constant `MI_WP_SIGNATURE` is declared as `0xFF515700`. Convert this to a signed integer and you get `-11054848`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info! So Windows totally kills my "user value", and there is nothing I can do about it, right?

Comment: @tmighty: I don't know of a way to prevent Windows from overwriting the message extra info. The documentation for [`GetMessageExtraInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644954.aspx) holds the following clue: *The meaning of the extra information is device specific.* My interpretation is, that this is *driver-defined* rather than *application-defined*, but the documentation is anything but clear on this particular topic.